# How to create a Sharepoint 2013 form to update a Sharepoint SQL database

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, external-list, sql

I have a SQL database, I have created an External Content Type and an External List for the Table.  I can see the list in SharePoint.  I would like to be able to change the form to add a new instance so it is more user-friendly.  Users will only be able to create new instances, not update or view any others. I would also like for a few of the columns to be a drop down that the choices are in another table.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would like to be able to change the form to add a new instance so it is more user friendly.**

If you need to make your form User-friendly you should use InfoPath to customize it , Check [How to: Customize External List Forms Using Microsoft InfoPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554886.aspx)

**Users will only be able to create new instances, not update or view any others.**

- You can manage this during configuring the External Content Type by Selecting `Create Operation`

  - The Create Operation is used by the External List when data is being created. The Create Operation contains the statement allowing data to be inserted into the table.
- You also can manage this via permission by creating Permission Level `Only_add` and assign this to group and set the users for this group

**I would also like for a few of the columns to be a drop down that the choices are in another table**

Unfortunately, There are not Lookups fields.
 the only thing that you can do a look up on in an external list is on the ID column, anything else and you are out of luck.

See also [External List Limitations in SharePoint 2010/2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/01/external-list-limitations-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thank you!  I have been trying and trying and could not get it to let me do drop downs.  Just know if I told some that I would need back up.  LOL

Comment: Dear  @meck2003 There are not Lookups fields because it's limitation as I told you in my answer , I hope it helps you